# How can I make redis HMSET with EXPIRE atomic with Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, amazon-elasticache

For caching a map I want to set TTL,
for now, I am doing like this

```
try {
  redisSyncCommand.hmset(key, map);  
  redisSyncCommand.expire(key, TTL);
} catch(Exception ex) {
  redisSyncCommand.expire(key, TTL);
}
```

However I have a timeout of 6s from my service end, so if hmset takes more than 6s, it times out.
So even in the catch block, If I expire the key.. in reality, Redis might still be hmset-ting the map and expire happens first and then hmset happens.. so it remains in the cache forever. how can I solve this?

Comment: Redis should keep the order of the commands, I don't see how EXPIRE will happen before the HMSET returns

Comment: expire of the catch... block